# why is An extra worker thread created during the process startup?

Tags: windows, msvcrt, crt

I am running a simple windows console application:-
When the control comes at main I dumped the stack--

_
My main thread's stack:

```
5840    0   Main Thread Main Thread Normal


console.exe!wmain(int argc=1, wchar_t * * argv=0x006831a0)

console.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  

console.exe!wmainCRTStartup()

kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()

ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()

ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

__

**The above is fine by why do I see this at startup ??:**

```
3740    0   Worker Thread   Win32 Thread Normal
```

Stack:

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()  
ntdll.dll!_ZwDelayExecution@8()
ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()
ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()
```

Comment: Some part of the runtime library, or Windows, will be creating another thread. Why does that bother you?

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?..so whenever I create a process, actually 2 threads are created ? what does the other thread do ?

Comment: "pathetic Community"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

LdrInitializeThunk is the method to setup a new thread. I did create with VS2008 a plain Win32 console application (no MFC,ATL) and get only one thread. Only when I attach a debugger I get a second one because the debugger injects a thread to enable debugging of the process. 
Process startup is covered in great detail in the book [here](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/4354a.aspx) where nothing is mentioned that a second thread is needed. Asynchronous Procedure Calls [APCs](http://www.opening-windows.com/techart_windows_vista_apc_internals.htm) are also not to blame. Perhaps your call stack was created with not all symbols loaded and you wrongly suspect the debugger helper thread as a hidden thread inside your application. When you have a look at your process with process explorer without a debugger you should see only one thread.

> Stage 6: Performing Process
>   Initialization in the Context of the
>   New Process
>
> KiInitializeContextThread, which is
>   called by KeInitializeThread, builds
>   the initial context of the thread and
>   the thread's kernel stack. The new
>   thread begins life running the
>   kernel-mode thread startup routine
>   KiThreadStartup. (For a more detailed
>   description of the thread startup
>   steps leading to this, see the section
>   "Flow of CreateThread.") The
>   KiThreadStartup routine performs the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Lowers the IRQL level from DPC/dispatch level to APC
>      (asynchronous procedure call) level.
> 2. Enables working set expansion.
> 3. Queues a user-mode APC to the new thread to execute the user-mode
>      thread startup routine
>      LdrInitializeThunk inside Ntdll.dll.